# Will any of the Doctors remember what happened in "The Day of the Doctor"?

Tags: doctor-who, the-day-of-the-doctor

Spoiler alert.

In "The Day of The Doctor", the Doctors agree that they won't remember trying to save Gallifrey, but other information around this site has made me think otherwise. Will any of the Doctors remember attempting to save Gallifrey rather than burn it?

> WARRIOR: I won't remember this, will I?
>
> DOCTOR: The time streams are out of sync. You can't retain it, no.
>
> WARRIOR: So I won't remember that I tried to save Gallifrey rather
>   than burn it. I'll have to live with that. But for now, for this
>   moment, I am the Doctor again. Thank you. Which one is mine? Ha!

So, will he eventually remember?

Oh, and before anyone answers this: I know, "timey wimey."

Comment: Eleventh does remember, so the answer would be yes: they will remember when they do the whole adventure again but from Eleventh's point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appeared to me that only the Doctor furthest along in the timeline would remember it. At first I thought that meant that the story was happening in Smiths timeline with the other 2 doctors meeting up with him. This would explain why any time 2 doctors meet, the later incarnation never remembers having met himself when he was the previous doctor (Smith does not remember meeting the Smith Doctor when he was the Tennant Doctor because The Tennant Doctor's memory is out of sync with the timelines) Thus Smith would remember meeting his younger self, but Tennant would not remember meeting his older self. This explains the possible paradoxes with earlier doctor cross-overs as well.

I originally though this would mean Smith would remember saving Gallifrey, but the others would not, but then got to thinking that Capaldi was actually the older doctor, so only he would remember having saved Gallifrey. This was actually hinted at when Clara and he are talking it he only "Thinks" he may have saved Gallifrey. This would be because he would not actually remember it, though he would find out that he did in Night of the Doctor. Later, he will cross the point in Capaldi's timeline when he actually did participate in saving Gallifrey (remember, "All 13 of us").

Just my 2 cents, but its the only way to make any sense of this wibley wobley timey wimey stuff.

Comment: I said not to say "timey wimey" in the answer >:(

Comment: @joeelectricity No you didn't, you just said you know. :P

Comment: This was already asked (similar enough question anyway) http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47734/time-stream-crossing-and-forgetfulness  and it was answered